# Console log in JS not logging in console

Tags: javascript

I have a HTML button lined to a JS function.
When I press the button the background turns green.
this works fine.

Now I want to log to the console.
But nothing gets logged to the console.
I must be missing something obvious:

```
function change_background(){
console.log('button pressed');
document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="java" onclick="change_background()")>
```

---

```js
function change_background(){
    console.log('button pressed');
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="java" onclick="change_background()")>
```

Comment: add your html code please

Comment: Can you also add a screenshot of the console?

Comment: Why is it working here in the code snippet section but not when i run it locally. the background changes colour no problem locally but i dont get the "button pressed" status

Answer (score -1):

It's probably something in your console, perhaps a filter in the options removing your log from appearing. Try restarting your browser or trying the code in another browser to see if it logs something out.